# Wait for multiple actions to finish in epic before dispatching action

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have a component where I dispatch multiple actions:

```
dispatch(action1());
dispatch(action2());
```

I have an epic which listens for both of those actions, and makes an ajax call for each:

```
export const fetchObservable = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(...actions) // wait for either action
    .mergeMap(({ url, method, body, success, error, responseType }) =>
      authenticate$
        .mergeMap(token => ajax$(url, method, body, token, responseType))
        .pluck('response')
        .mergeMap(response => Observable.of(success(response), hideLoading()))
        .startWith(showLoading())
        .catch(response => Observable.of(error(response)))
    );
```

I show a loading spinner with `showLoading()` and hide it with `hideLoading()`

The problem is that as soon as the first observable completes and `Observable.of(success(response), hideLoading())` is called, the loading spinner disappears.

The reducer for the loader looks like this:

```
const loader = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_LOADING:
      return true;
    case HIDE_LOADING:
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

How can I wait for both actions to finish before calling hideLoading? How would I develop a solution that waits for x number of dispatches in a component?

Comment: Observable.zip(action1Stream,action2Stream).subscribe()

Comment: Why are they separate actions?

Comment: @jayphelps they are multiple actions because they hit different APIs. If I did something like 
`const action1 = id => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(action2(id))
    dispatch(action3(id))
  }
}`  I think I would still run into the same problem wouldn't I?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that my suggestion is that if your business logic dictates that two API calls are made but you need to wait for them both to return before removing the loading indicator, that logic ideally belongs in your Epics. So your UI components dispatch a single action and a single Epic makes the two API calls together. When using middleware like redux-observable business logic should be in reducers + epics, not in UI components. Hope this helps!